# How can I download the list of all the branches which are in cloud bitbucket repository?

Tags: repository, git-filter-branch, bitbucket-cloud

Our repo size is more and we want to delete unwanted branches. For that I want to make a list of all branches im a particular repo. But no where I am seeing any such option.
Please guide.

Regards,

In Bitbucket CLoud

1. I tried to find Export or download option: Not found
2. Tried to copy manually the names of the branches. But it's showing thousands of branches. However i want only few fields like name of the branch, owner/created by, last modified date.